# 'TextView' gets cropped on a Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this simple 'XML' layout. I have tested in various devices and emulators and works fine. But on **Galaxy Tab Samsung 9.6inch (1280x800) 157 dpi**, text customer gets cropped in the end & becomes "*custom*".

I have read that i should declare dimens xml for various densities but i thought using DP is what makes your layout look the same in all devices. Am i wrong?

Also this tablet is a ldpi and x-large screen. I have tested it in other similar devices with similar specs and works well. How should i make this work for this device?

**NOTE** I want specifically 100dp to match others texts in width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelSelGateName"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:text="customer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod I dont want a library.I want native way.

Comment: set width as wrap_content

Comment: @Manivasagam I want specifically that dp to match others texts in width.If i put wrap_content thay will have different widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be the issue of TextSize in that device. Have you tried playing with the text size? 
Is this layout is in any other layout?

Comment: Also check the text Appearance within the settings of the device you have mentioned in your question.

Comment: Yes its inside of a constraint Layout.

Comment: That would be the issue of constraint Layout. Check the parent layout carefully or post the code here.

Comment: Eventually, the device's font was increased...go figure.Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Its happening because u have used padding on whole side.just set padding only top and bottom as u have only fixed the width.then it should be worked 
to support padding just follow below-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelSelGateName"
    android:layout_width="132dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_paddingLeft="16dp"
android:layout_paddingRight="16dp"
    android:text="customer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: These settings are more than enough to wrap the whole word.In other devices works well.

Comment: But its not a good practice.when u have set padding on left right side or top bottom then u must have kept enough space for placing padding on that side.suppose u set padding left right 10(5+5) dp then if your textview width is normally 100 dp then u have to increase it to 110 dp for proper view.

Comment: But i want exactly 16dp space on the left. How should i do that?

Comment: Yeah but, in the layout editor , 100dp is more the enough (leaving also some space to right). I dont understand why is different on this device. The DP width should be the same in all devices.

Comment: there's some screen dimension difference.That's why its happening.And for that android recommend to use same padding with enough space for padding.Anyway if this answer if right then please mark this answer right.

Comment: I will try it later and respond accordingly.